# How to change a JavaScript variable from user input field (in HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

I have checked many posts, but either

a) They didn't work for me
b) or I don't understand them

I have gotten all the pages of a textbook uploaded to a website, from which I am fetching the images 1 by 1 into a html file which I will upload to the school server once complete.

I have page navigation systems through `Next` and `Previous` Buttons. I am now trying to create an input-based way to get to a page by typing its number. I have tried something which I think **should theoretically work**

Below is a code snippet with my current "website".

```js
function PlusPage() {
  a = a + 1
  b = "example.com/" + a + ".png"
  document.getElementById("page").src = b
}

var a = 1;
var b

function RemPage() {
  a = a - 1
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a
  b = "example.com/" + a + ".png"
  document.getElementById("page").src = b
}

function doStuff() {
  var nameElement = document.getElementById("someInput");
  a = nameElement.value
  b = "example.com/" + a + ".png"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button class="button button1" onclick="PlusPage()">Next Page </button>
  <button class="button button1" onclick="RemPage()">Previous Page </button>
  <br><br>
  <img id="page" src="example.com/1.png" alt="">
  <br>The below textbox should alter the page. but instead, the whole thing stops functioning.
  <input id="someInput" type="text">
  <input type="button" value="Go to Page" onClick="doStuff()">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You forgot `document.getElementById("page").src = b` Also, `RemPage` causes a null pointer error since there's no element with `id="demo"`. Remove that line. On an unrelated note, what about creating a PDF...?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that silly error :D. And regarding your second question, I cant make it into a PDF - it is against the publisher's rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were just missing one simple line of code from the `doStuff` function:
`document.getElementById("page").src = b;`. Plus as mentioned, there was no element with the ID `demo`.

---

### Edit

I've also included some validation for you, the user should be unable to go to page anything less than 1 with this implementation and they shouldn't be able to go past 355 either. If you like you could include some error feedback, i.e. invalid number, or too low, or too high, etc.

```js
var a = 1;
var b;
var minPage = 1;

// change this to the last relevant page if you like 
var maxPage = 355; // got this from the Acknowledgements page 

function PlusPage() {
    
    // validation
    if (a  >= maxPage) { return; }
    
    a = a + 1
    b = "example.com/" + a + ".png"
    document.getElementById("page").src = b
}

function RemPage() {
    
    // validation
    if (a  <= minPage) { return; }
    
    a = a - 1
    b = "example.com/" + a + ".png"
    document.getElementById("page").src = b
}

function doStuff() {
    var nameElement = document.getElementById("someInput");
    
    // validation
    if (nameElement.value > maxPage) { return; }
    if (nameElement.value < minPage) { return; }
    
    a = nameElement.value;
    b = "example.com/" + a + ".png";
    document.getElementById("page").src = b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Book Navigation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="button button1" onclick="PlusPage()">Next Page </button>
        <button class="button button1" onclick="RemPage()">Previous Page </button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <img id="page" src="example.com/1.png" alt="">
        <br>
        The below textbox should alter the page. but instead, the whole thing stops functioning.
        <input id="someInput" type="text">
        <input type="button" value="Go to Page" onClick="doStuff()">
    </body>
</html>
```

---

### Edit 2

This is how I'd personally do it, it's considered bad practice to use HTML attributes such as `onclick` or `onchange`, etc, seeing as you can easily do it in JS. I know this is only a basic JS application and there's no real need to get into a debate over what's the best way to do it, but as a quick script that works and is reliable, this is how I'd personally do it.

**Note**, if you have any other scripts on your page, it can be a pretty good idea to separate your code, it's awful, on any scale of project to have things delcared on the global scope, using a self invoked function allows the code to run **as if** it 's just placed on the global scope, however you cannot access the variables outside of the self invoked function, example being adding `console.log(a);` to the end of the JS, that will cause an error as the variable `a` is undefined on the global scope.

**Plus**, if you do add `console.log(a);` to the last line, while it'll cause console errors, it won't actually affect the application itself at all. So it allows the code itself to be more reliable too, in addition to much easier to manage.

```js
/**
 * @description this is a self invoked function, the purpose of
 * making this code into a self invoked function  is to ensure that 
 * this code does not interfere with any other potential code that  
 * you may have on the page, i.e. other js scripts/libs/framworks
 */
!function () {
    // change this to the last relevant page if you like 
    var maxPage = 355; // got this from the Acknowledgments page 
    var a = 1;
    var b = null;
    var minPage = 1;
    var $ = function(x) { return document.querySelector(x); };
    var events = function(x, y, fnc) {
        var list = x.split(" ");
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i ++) {
            y.addEventListener(list[i], fnc);
        }
        return void 0;
    };
    
    events("click", $('#nextPage'), PlusPage);
    events("click", $('#prevPage'), RemPage);
    events("keypress keyup keydown", $('#someInput'), doStuff);
  
  
    function goTo(p) {
        var start = "example.com/",
            end = ".png";
        $("#page").src = start + p + end;
    } 

    function PlusPage() {
        // validation
        if (a >= maxPage) { return; }
        goTo(++a);
    }

    function RemPage() {
        // validation
        if (a <= minPage) { return; }
        goTo(--a);
    }

    function doStuff() {
        var val = this.value;
        var firstPage = function () {
            b = "example.com/" + 1 + ".png";
            $("#page").src = b;
            return;
        };
        // validation
        if (val == '') { return firstPage(); } 
        if (isNaN(val)) { return; } // isNaN = is not a number 
        if (val > maxPage) { return; }
        if (val < minPage) { return; }
        a = val;
        b = "example.com/" + a + ".png";
        $("#page").src = b;
    }
}();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Book Navigation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="button button1" id="nextPage">Next Page </button>
        <button class="button button1" id="prevPage">Previous Page </button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <img id="page" src="example.com/1.png" alt="">
        <br>
        <p> 
            The below textbox should alter the page. 
            But instead, the whole thing stops functioning.
        </p>
        <input id="someInput" type="text">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After entering a page number to go to, i can get to that page, but the **Next** and **Previous** buttons don't have any effect anymore. Help!

Comment: Hey @Suda I'll help you out I  a bit, it's 7am where I am, just getting ready for work haha!

Comment: Hey @Suda I just got into work, can you open up the console and tell me exactly what it says? - It works fine in my browser, I'm assuming it's a stupid cross browser issue.

Comment: @Suda the second way I've done it may actually work. Give it a try? - I've made some minor improvements to the code, if you need me to explain it to you, I'm more than happy to do so, I work with JS every day, so y'know.

Comment: That explains a lot... I'm the other side of the world, U.K. but sure no problem, let me know if you have any further issues, I'll help as much as I can.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It finally works. BTW, I am using Chrome on Windows 64-bit, Version 64.0

Comment: What does **goTo(++a)** and **!function** do? (JS for Dummies doesn't tell me :D)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166864/discussion-between-suda-and-jo3-w3b-d3v).